# adb forward remote port to local machine

Tags: android, port, forwarding, adb

This is a query regarding the usage of adb on android.

Is there a way to forward the remote port i.e. port on the android device/emulator to the local machine to which the device is connected?

$ adb forward tcp:port1 tcp:port2 # forwards the local port port1 on the machine to port2 on the device.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm in a similar situation right now, but I think I'll just going down the different route: Bind the app to 127.0.0.1:12345 and tunnel to that port. Why do you care so much who initiates the connection? Once you have a TCP connection established, both sides can talk/listen?

Answer (score 33):

Recently google updated ADB service. And added `reverse` command that should do the job.

From [reverse](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/SERVICES.TXT) documentation:

> This implements the `adb reverse` feature, i.e. the ability to reverse
>       socket connections from a device to the host. `<forward-command>` is one
>       of the forwarding commands that are described above, as in:
>
> 1. `list-forward`
> 2. `forward:<local>;<remote>`
> 3. `forward:norebind:<local>;<remote>`
> 4. `killforward-all`
> 5. `killforward:<local>`
>
> Note that in this case, `<local>` corresponds to the socket on the device
>       and `<remote>` corresponds to the socket on the host.
>
> The output of `reverse:list-forward` is the same as host:list-forward
>       except that `<serial>` will be just `host`.

Comment: This answer is outdated and broken, but the feature still exists and works. The correct command structure is

`adb reverse tcp:8888 tcp:9999`

See `adb --help` for details!

Answer (score 1):

Do you truly need to forward the port or are you just looking for a way to communicate using sockets from a program running on the android shell to your host machine? I was able to accomplish the latter by sending my message to the port of interest on "10.0.2.2", which is the loopback adapter of the host machine. See docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#emulatornetworking).

**EDIT**
This is the updated [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#overview)

Comment: How would one accomplish this with a device rather than the emulator?

Comment: @Johnny On a real device, you would use adb reverse. For instance, if you have a server on your host listening on port 8080 and you'd like to reverse-forward port 8000 on your device to it,  you'd use `adb reverse tcp:8000 tcp:8080`

Comment: @sacha I cannot find any documentation on adb reverse command. Does it actually exist? What versions of SDK?

Comment: @akuz According to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/252586941934d23073a8d167ec240b221062505f, adb reverse was added to the android code in May 2014