# "adb forward" a port from remote to host

Tags: java, android, tcp, adb, portforwarding

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415797/adb-forward-remote-port-to-local-machine) question, which asks the same thing, but the answer to that seems to work on for the emulator, while I need it to work on the device.

The only command I've run has been `adb forward tcp:port tcp:port`, which seems to only allow unidirectional communication, in the direction of host->remote. I need remote->host. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I believe you want a client - server model

Comment: I thought so too, but the communication itself has been the problem, not the architecture of the code.